# Semantic-UI Button Popup

Tags: html, styling, semantic-ui

I am trying to make a buttons popup with Semantic UI. Following [their guide](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html) I made an inline popup:

```js
// Button Popups
$('.popup-button').popup({
 inline: true,
 on: 'click',
 position: 'top center'
});
```

```html
<button class='ui right floated tiny circular icon button popup-button'><i class='ui share alternate icon'></i></button>
<div class='ui flowing popup'>
 <div class='ui buttons'>
  <button class='ui icon facebook button'><i class='ui icon facebook'></i></button>
  <button class='ui icon google plus button'><i class='ui icon google plus'></i></button>
  <button class='ui icon twitter button'><i class='ui icon twitter'></i></button>
 </div>
</div>
```

But the buttons doesn't fit. I would like to do the buttons as the popup, with no white borders or alikes. Is it possible with Semantic-UI?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a custom selector to help link the popup contents to its activator. In this example initialize your *flowing popup* with link to your *popup button*.

```
$('.popup-button').popup({
    popup : $('.flowing.popup'),
    on    : 'click'
});
```

You can also specify popup content to **data-value** attribute in activator element.

```
<button class='ui center floated tiny circular icon button popup-button1' data-html="<div class='ui buttons'><button class='ui icon facebook button'><i class='ui icon facebook'></i></button><button class='ui icon google plus button'><i class='ui icon google plus'></i></button><button class='ui icon twitter button'><i class='ui icon twitter'></i></button></div>" ><i class='ui share alternate icon'> </i></button>
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nighisha/j3rdhkok/2/)

You can get rid of white borders by removing padding of the popup div.